# Which linter prompts warning/error in VSC

Tags: python, linter

after having some Python courses I am starting with my first own project I am using (VSC).
My environment is derived from one of those courses requirements.txt, which includes several support tools like linters. Meanwhile I can't really remember anymore which tool is used for what ;)
Accordingly I am used to get several error messages for one error, what is fine for me for real issues. Unfortunately I also have some long lines in my code I want to keep, so those messages won't disappear by correcting my code.
I managed to include a settings file for Flake8 as for its error message the source linter is  mentioned. But some other linter tool still gives me annoying line-too-long-warnings in the Problems tab as well as inline.

-> Which linter produces the error message given below and how can I disable E501 errors for it ? The remaining line-too-long-error can be supressed by adding *# noqa: E501* at the end of the long line, I guess that helps to identify the correponding linter.
-> Is there a way to find out which linter prompts the errors/warning in the Problems tab in general ?

Thanks in advance !

---

**error message:**
Line too long (90 > 88 characters) Ruff(E501)

---

**requirements.txt:**

```
pip
setuptools

# Libraries
ipython
ipykernel
loguru
Cython

# Testing
pytest
codecov
pytest-cov
tox
pre-commit
pytest-benchmark

# Linting
flake8
pylint
mypy
autopep8
isort
black==21.4b0

# Documentation
mkdocs
mkdocstrings
mkdocs-material
Pygments

# Project specific Libraries:
selenium
pandas
```

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: You [probably] don't need to run multiple linters, for starters

Comment: @JRiggles
True, but I just started with the template from my course

Comment: @Diego Borba
Thanks for advice. 
I guess I managed to include the error message and the requirements.txt content after a while.

Comment: Looking at the error message "...Ruff(E501)" I'd guess it is [ruff](https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff).